# How do we experimentally estimate the luminosity of a distant star?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, spectroscopy, stars, luminosity

While calculating the matter density of the universe, we need to find luminosity. How do we experimentally estimate the luminosity of a star?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to measure the flux, preferably across *all* wavelengths - a.k.a. the bolometric flux.  If you cannot do that then you need to measure the flux in as many wavebands as possible or obtain a flux-calibrated spectrum over as wavelength range as possible. A flux in specified wavebands can be converted to a bolometric flux using [bolometric corrections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolometric_correction) or you can extrapolate and integrate from a fit to the observed part of the spectrum to work out the bolometric flux.

You then multiply the observed bolometric flux from the star by $4\pi D^2$, where $D$ is the distance to the star, and correct for absorption and scattering by intervening material if necessary.

If you don't know the distance to a star, but know what kind of star it is, then a luminosity can be indirectly estimated by comparing it to stars of similar type or with model predictions.

There are some (rare) types of star (e.g Cepheids) where periodic variation is related to their luminosity and so the luminosity can be estimated by measuring that variability.

Comment: I was seeking for the Experimental Calculation of Luminosity . But thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SambhavAntriksh I don't understand. Calculate means calculate?

Comment: Well I am sorry . I was just asking how do we experimentally get the value of Luminosity. What do we measure , while doing this experimentally ? Which data we dig for it?